# Как посчитать среднее значение первых строк каждого часа

Tags: sql, sql-server

У нас существует таблица со значениями, каждые пять минут в таблице появляется новая строка с числовым значением и временем, как посчитать среднее значение за первые 45 минут каждого часа.

У меня есть запрос, который считает среднее значение за каждый час:

```sql
SELECT hh=CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126), 
       [Fe_Ka]=AVG([Fe_ka]) 
FROM Results1 
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126) 
ORDER BY hh;
```

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать самостоятельно, с чем у вас проблемы? Тут помогают с затруднениями, а не решают задачи целиком за вас.

Comment: у меня есть запрос, который считает среднее значение за каждый час
SELECT hh=CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126), [Fe_Ka]=AVG([Fe_ka])
FROM Results1
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(13),[DateMeasure],126)
ORDER BY hh;

Comment: @CrazyElf но как сделать выборку по 45 минутам в начале каждого часа я совсем не представляю

Comment: Добавляйте код непосредственно в вопрос. Вы можете его редактировать. Ну, значит надо выделить из времени минуты и сделать условие на то, что эти минуты <= 45. Всё остальное в запросе кажется вообще менять не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

как возможный пример

```
CREATE TABLE
#test11 (
  value int,
  times time)
```

```
INSERT INTO #test11 (value, times)
  VALUES (8, '01:00:00'), (71, '01:05:00'), (79, '01:10:00'), (82, '01:15:00'), (16, '01:20:00'), (55, '01:25:00'), (41, '01:30:00'), (85, '01:35:00'),
  (74, '01:40:00'), (71, '01:45:00'), (27, '01:50:00'), (62, '01:55:00'), (7, '02:00:00'), (100, '02:05:00'), (50, '02:10:00'), (77, '02:15:00'),
  (15, '02:20:00'), (57, '02:25:00'), (27, '02:30:00'), (47, '02:35:00'), (2, '02:40:00'), (78, '02:45:00'), (91, '02:50:00'), (63, '02:55:00'),
  (93, '03:00:00'), (92, '03:05:00'), (55, '03:10:00'), (95, '03:15:00'), (91, '03:20:00'), (3, '03:25:00'), (84, '03:30:00'), (86, '03:35:00'),
  (6, '03:40:00'), (92, '03:45:00'), (11, '03:50:00'), (64, '03:55:00')
```

```
SELECT
  hour,
  AVG(value)
FROM (SELECT
  DATENAME(mi, times) AS minute,
  DATENAME(hh, times) AS hour,
  *
FROM #test11) AA
WHERE AA.minute <= 45
GROUP BY hour
```

Comment: этак проще подстроки извлечь часа и минут по ним отфильтровать и сгруппировать.